# How to highlight unique data value in two different columns of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

I want to highlight the repeating data values in two different columns of a dataframe. 
For example:

```
df1:

item Node

A      B

A      C

A      D

B      A

C      A
```

I want the output to come like:

```
item Node Same

A      B  False

A      C  False

A      D  False

B      A  True

C      A  True
```

I want to show the duplicate values like if there is an A-B I want to highlight B-A. For this I created another dataframe and interchanged the values of the two columns.

df2:

```
item   node

B      A

C      A

D      A

A      B

A      C
```

I am trying to check as df1['item']==df2['node'] and df1['node']==df2['item'] , if it comes as true then the value is repeated. As A comes in df1 item it checks for A in df2 node and corresponding to that it checks that A's corresponding node B comes in df2's item column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\eumukar\Desktop\test data xl.xlsx')
df1=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['item','node'])
df2=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['node','item'])
df1['Same']=np.where((df1['item']==df2['node']) & (df1['node']==df2['item']),'True','False')
print(df1)
```

I am getting the output as:

```
item node   Same
 A    B  False
 A    C  False
 A    D  False
 B    A  False
 C    A  False
```

Comment: Is possible there is another row `A      B` in `df1`? If yes what is expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all pairs `item` with `Node` are not duplicted use `np.sort` (if performance is important) with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df1['Same'] = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df1[['item','Node']], axis=1), index=df.index).duplicated()
print (df1)
  item Node   Same
0    A    B  False
1    A    C  False
2    A    D  False
3    B    A   True
4    C    A   True
```

Comment: For  "bigger" datasets, this is the only solution that scales well and will be efficient.

Comment: @arush05 Just a reminder:  If an answer has solved your issue, ***please*** remember to click the Tick mark to "Accept" it.  This will remove it from the "unsolved issues" list (so people don't waste their time trying to fix it again), tell anyone searching for the same issue what the solution is (so *they* don't waste time searching when the solution is right here), *and* it will encourage people to answer your other questions in future.

Answer (score 3):

List comprehension:

```
df["same"] = [True if len(df.loc[df["Node"].eq(i)])>1 else False for i in df["Node"]]
print (df)

  item Node   same
0    A    B  False
1    A    C  False
2    A    D  False
3    B    A   True
4    C    A   True
```

Or `np.where`:

```
s = set(df.loc[df["Node"].duplicated(),"Node"])
df["same"] = np.where(df["Node"].isin(s), True, False)
print (df)

  item Node   same
0    A    B  False
1    A    C  False
2    A    D  False
3    B    A   True
4    C    A   True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert each row to `frozenset` and use the method `duplicated`:

```
df.apply(frozenset, axis=1).duplicated()
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Although apply frozenset works, I used it couple of times on bigger datasets and it's extremely slow. You should test it yourself.

Comment: @Erfan Of course. It's not a parallelized computation. It's a good solution if you have a small data set and don't want to write much code.